# NameError: undefined method `xmlschema' for class `Time' while running spec file using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**Issue Details**

```
NameError: undefined method `xmlschema' for class `Time'
./config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require_relative'
./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
./spec/models/customer_group_spec.rb:3:in `require'
./spec/models/customer_group_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

**Here is my rails_helper.rb class**

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

**Here is the customer_group_spec.rb file**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CustomerGroup, type: :model do
  describe 'associations' do
    it { should have_many(:users) }
  end

  describe 'validations' do
    subject { build(:customer_group) }

    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:title) }
  end

  describe 'scopes' do
    describe '.active' do
      it 'returns only active customer groups' do
        active_group = create(:customer_group, is_active: true)
        inactive_group = create(:customer_group, is_active: false)

        expect(CustomerGroup.active).to eq([active_group])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**environment.rb file is**

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

**application.rb file is**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails'
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require 'active_model/railtie'
require 'active_job/railtie'
require 'active_record/railtie'
require 'active_storage/engine'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
require 'action_mailbox/engine'
require 'action_text/engine'
require 'action_view/railtie'
require 'action_cable/engine'
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module ProjectBackend
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0
    config.time_zone = 'Dhaka'
    config.autoloader = :classic
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/models/)
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
    config.api_only = true
    config.i18n.available_locales = %i(en bn)
    config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
  end
end
```

Comment: and the ../config/environment file?

Comment: The error mentions `../config/environment` and `xmlschema`, but there is no detail provided of that file and no mention of that code in the information you have shared.

Comment: added application.rb file for more details

Comment: It isn't clear on what line error happens from the code snippets that were posted. But it seems the issue is missing `require 'time'` because the `Time.xmlschema` method is implemented in StdLib, not in the CoreLib.